# sum up values based on elements in a numerical named list in r

Tags: r

Assuming I have the following simplified named list

```
tbl1 <- c(a=5,b=3,c=6)
```

and a second list of characters

```
lst2 <- c("abbacb","aacb")
```

How can I calculate the sum for each string in `lst2` based on the values in `tbl1`?

To be more precise, the "abbacb" should give 5+3+3+5+6+3=25 while the "aacb" = 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `strsplit` into a `list` of charactters.  Then, use the named vector to replace the values by matching with the `names` of the 'tbl1' and get the `sum` of the replaced values

```
sapply(strsplit(lst2, ""), function(x) sum(tbl1[x]))
#[1] 25 19
```

---

Or another option is to replace within the string without splitting and then do an `eval`uation

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_replace_all(str_replace_all(lst2, "(?<=.)(?=.)", "+"), 
  setNames(as.character(tbl1), names(tbl1))), 
       function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
 #5+3+3+5+6+3     5+5+6+3 
 #      25          19
```